# Angular-Kendo TreeView - working with div and span templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, kendo-ui

Within a Angular-Kendo treeview `<div>`, I'm having a bit of trouble styling a `<div>` element which I want to show on a hover event.

Here is an image of the treeview without the icon options to the right of each node:

[image: kendo treeview]

However I'd like to show some icons to the right once I hover on a node, as follows :

[image]

your advice is appreciated...

Here's the HTML (please notice the Kendo `k-template` directive used here):

```
   <div id="treeview" kendo-tree-view             
                k-options="nav.treeOptions"
                k-data-source="nav.reportsTreeDataSource"
                k-on-change="nav.onTreeSelect(dataItem)">



 <span k-template>{{dataItem.text}}
             <span class="templ-icons">               
                <a title="add new folder" ng-click="nav.addAfter(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></a>&nbsp;
                <a title="add report here" ng-click="nav.addBelow(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>&nbsp;
                <a title="remove" ng-click="nav.remove(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a> 
             </span>
        </span>

</div>
```

and of course, I want ONLY want to show the icon options when a user hovers over any particular node (i.e. could be at the folder level, or at the leaf level).

and the CSS :

```
<style scoped>
.templ-icons {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:smaller;
    font-style: italic;
    color: white;  
}

#treeview:hover > .templ-icons {
    opacity:1.0;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you make a small directive for this? Check out this example I put together with my `toggle-preview` directive. I'm not including any kendo controls, but you should be able to add something like this to your custom template. You might need to make some small changes, and you can of course make it more robust, but this seems like a good situation to use something like this, and you can use whichever element you would like be it `<span>` `<div>` etc.

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/c97pmdnj/)

```
<span toggle-preview>item a</span>
```

---

```
.active::after { 
    content: url(~/icon.gif);
}
```

---

```
app.directive('togglePreview', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('mouseenter', function() {
                elem.addClass('active');
            });
            elem.on('mouseleave', function() {
                elem.removeClass('active');
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

### Edit

Per discussion we want to attach all three pre-defined icons, and attach a `ng-click` handler to the icon with some sort of sense of knowing which icon we clicked. Here is a solution that is driven on a naming convention and utilizing the `$compile` service for directive injection based on the icon values we provide in the parent `attr`

### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f49kphL)

```
<div toggle-preview ico="plus delete folder" >item a</div>
```

---

```
.add::after {
    content: url(~/iconA.gif);
}

.delete::after { 
    content: url(~/iconB.gif);
}

.folder::after { 
    content: url(~/iconC.gif);
}
```

---

```
app.directive('togglePreview', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            var classes = attrs.ico.split(' ');

            elem.on('mouseenter', function(){
                angular.forEach(classes, function(e, i) {

                    var node = $compile('<span ng-click="clickIco($event)"><img src="//~' + e + '.gif" ico="'+ e +'"/><span>')(scope);
                    elem.append(node);
                })
            });
            elem.on('mouseleave', function(){
                elem.children().remove();
            });

            scope.clickIco = function($event){
                console.log($event.target.attributes.ico.value);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: thanks for that great idea. Can I specify multiple images in the .active class ? I'll need three at the folder, as per the requirements (add/ del folder, add report). Then somehow I need to figure out if I'm also at the bottom leaf node (i.e. a report name), then I need to display the DELETE icon.

Comment: and I'll need to add the ng-click event, which I believe I can handle in your directive idea.

Comment: Sure, you can put an `attr` on the directive and concat a relating css class with the specified image. I am simply doing background colors, but the idea is the same- just change the images. `ng-click` should also be no issue for you - See fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/c97pmdnj/1/

Comment: yes indeed, I was thinking the same thing about adding additional classes. I tried it here but I can't get the icons to line up to the right. In other words, each span needs to display all three icons. They're overwriting each other in my example. http://jsfiddle.net/c97pmdnj/2/

Comment: @bob try following along with my example here http://jsfiddle.net/e1wazdpg/. The determining variable is defined on the html element with `ico="whichever"`

Comment: Oh I see, all three. Let me see what I can do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69313/discussion-between-bob-and-sal-niro).